# shorten value in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I need an oracle statement that shortens values:

`value[1] = user1@email.de
 value[2] = xyz@email.de`

to

`value[1] = user1
 value[2] = xyz`

Thus, something like

`Update table set value = replace('@email.de','',value)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression would be:

```
Update table
    set value = replace(value, '@email.de', '')
    where value like '%@email.de';
```

The value with the strings to be replaced is the first argument.  I would also use a `where` clause, so only the necessary updates are done.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `instr` to find where `@` appear and `substr` till that position.

```
 select 
   column,
   substr(column, 1, instr(column,'@')-1) extracted 
 from your_table;
```